# IntelliJ Version Control for Gradle Project

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, version-control

I am new to using version control and I don't know how to manage my external libraries(imported by gradle). If I want to include version control in my gradle project do I have to add the `build.gradle` file in my git repository or is there a setting to automatically add the external libraries?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do need to add `build.gradle` to your version control. Otherwise there is no way to know which external libraries are needed when someone checks out the project on a different machine.